# Как записать несколько значений в одно поле SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Пробовал вот так, думал будет работать:

```
$full_name = array($_POST['name1'], $_POST['name2'], $_POST['name3']);
```

В ячейке получается **array**.

Comment: $full_name = $_POST['name1'] .' '. $_POST['name2'] .' '. $_POST['name3'];

конкатенация - 


  http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php

Comment: спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 1):

Надо сделать в базе **три** ячейки, и записать в них значения **по отдельности.**
Если понадобится полное имя, то склеивать **при получении**.

Других вариантов **нет**.

Comment: Судя по всему автор просто хотел 3 значения склеить и записать в строчку. А не создать массив внутри ячейки. Вы поняли вопрос не правильно

Comment: Способ от Deonis именно то что я хотел, 3 разных значения в одному ячейку через пробел

Answer (score 1):

MySQL здесь совершенно не при чем. Склить знаения в одну строку можно через конкатенацию или подстановкой переменных в стоку в двойных кавычках или в heredoc.
Всё это доступно описано в родной документации: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php
Пример:

```
$a = "Hello {$username}! See you at {$time} tomorrow.";
$b = $a . ' Hasta la vista';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$full_name = array($_POST['name1'], $_POST['name2'], $_POST['name3']);
$odna_yacheika = implode(', ',$full_name);
echo $odna_yacheika; //name1, name2, name3
```